# How to calculate Test Error

Tags: probability, machine-learning

I'm reading 机器学习 (directly translated - Machine Learning). I'm at a part where the author illustrates how to calculate what he calls Out of Training Error (OTE) - test error in English. He provides the following equation I am trying to understand:

[image: Full equation and explanation]

For some algorithm L<sub>a</sub> which is a function some set of training data *X*, with "perfect" function *f* (perfect here meaning that it works for all cases **if** I've understood up to this point) is equal to:

- $\sum_{h}$ = I don't understand this part. *H* is equal to the hypothesis space (but as far as I can tell is unused). *h* he defines as some potential hypothesis resulting from using algorithm L<sub>a</sub> on training data *X*. What I don't understand is what is being summed up. Is it all the possible hypothesis in the hypothesis space?
- $\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}-X}$ where $\mathcal{X}$ is the hypothesis space and *X* is the training data (as mentioned above). Is this saying for each training data in the set of the training data minus hypothesis? I don't understand how you could subtract training data from a hypothesis.

Last clarification, he says the notation:

[image: notation]

is saying if the result is true than the value is 1 otherwise it is 0. If I understand the rest, it means the probability of the occurrence of *x* (I'm hazy on this since I don't understand the sum) multiplied by the above mentioned boolean equation multiplied by the probability of *h* occurring given some training data *X* and algorithm L<sub>a</sub>.

Comment: pretty sure "out of training error" refers to the test error instead

Comment: @5201314, the test error is an unbiased estimate of the "out of training error", but it is only an estimate, not the actual value of the "out of training error", which of course in most cases cannot be known, since we don't usually  know the true function $f(x)$, or even usually the true distribution $P(x)$. Although, we can know those things if we choose them, which is sometimes done when studying learning algorithms, regularization techniques, etc.

Comment: @Joe yes that's what I meant, said this just cuz OP mentioned "Out of Training Error (OTE) - I assume that's just training error in English"

Comment: oh, I see. Yes, I submitted an edit for the title, since it is missing the "Out of", which I see now why.

Comment: I updated the title and body to reflect the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_h$ is a sum over all hypotheses in the hypothesis set. I assume this would have to be an integral if your hypothesis space is not discrete.

$\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X} \setminus X}$ is saying that you sum over all of the points in the data space $\mathcal{X}$, that were NOT in your training set $X$. That’s odd to me. I’m used to the generalization error being on points randomly drawn from the data space, using the data distribution $P(x)$, NOT intentionally excluding the training set.

$\mathbb{I}(h(x)\ne f(x))$ is an indicator function that is one when the hypothesis predicts an incorrect label.

$P(h | X, \mathcal{L}_a)$ is the probability of the learning algorithm selecting hypothesis $h$ as the learned hypothesis, given training set $X$.

All of those parts put together give you an equation that is measuring the expected classification error for the learned hypothesis on points randomly drawn points from the data space, where the expectation is over the randomness of the data drawn, with distribution $P(x)$, AND over the randomness of the hypothesis learned by the algorithm, which has distribution $P(h | X, \mathcal{L}_a)$.

Comment: He does mention that it is discrete (离散) but your pointing out that if it weren't would require an integral is helpful so I figure I'll leave it as is.